# How to get menu on new pages created

Tags: sharepoint-online, menu

I need to recreate a Menu on a different site collections. I am inheriting the navigation from the parent site,
then made a copy of the page and put it on the new site
but now I need to know how to change the page to a modern page instead of a webpart page but I still need to keep the menu but I still do not see the menu.

Can someone assist me here?